# Meaning of understatment and annual round

Tags: meaning

Can please explain me the meaning of the following sentence:

> Painting the town red is an understatement in Bali especially when the
>   Mimaisa Festival makes its annual round.

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll break it all down for you:

> Painting the town red

this is an idiom meaning basically to go out and have a good time; celebrating, drinking, eating.

> is an understatement

to call it "painting the town red" does not communicate the full impact of what happens.

> in Bali

Bali is an island in Indonesia.

> especially when the Mimaisa festival

Presumably, this is a public party-style event related to "mimaisa" (I couldn't find anything specific about it).

> makes its annual round

when used as a noun, a "round" can refer to a route or circuit normally or habitually covered by someone or something; "annual" means it happens every year.

So:

> To call what people in Bali do "partying" or "celebrating" does not adequately communicate what they really do, especially when it's the time of year that the Mimaisa Festival is happening again.

Comment: A well-crafted answer.  +1